# apache server is confusing with HTTPService responses

Tags: php, apache, solaris

This is a very weird problem.
I have an apache server on solaris with php.
I wrote two php scripts that return values.
Sometimes, when I run the php scripts urls on the same time, the apache server returns the result of one php script to the other php page.

I tried to minimize the problem by write two php script:

1. hello.php - print hello
2. world.php - print world

sometimes when i run them on the same time by url, the hello.php return world.

when i'm using html pages it's working just fine so i think the problem is in the php installed on the server.

I'm a flex developer and I thought that the problem is in my flex client application but after I just run the php scripts directly, I see that the problem is in the server itself.

somebody know this problem?
thank you very much.

Comment: Where do the php scripts get their value from? Using a common cache?

Comment: The simple example, they just print a string.
when one php script print "hello" and the other one print "world"
sometimes when i run them in the same time, the script that need to say "hello", say "world".

Comment: Weird! No APC/Memcache active? No accessing session variables, nothing? Really just the boiled down hello world?

Comment: no. It's very strage and it has an affect on my all web applications.
very sucks.
I need solution.

Comment: I don't know anything about Solaris, but it seems to me a bug of php on that platform...

which version of solaris, php, apache are you using?

Comment: This implies something is very broken in the code for Apache or PHP. Since its sloaris, I'm guessing you might be running the threaded Apache rather than the prefork? And PHP as a module? If so try using a fastCGI PHP and see if the problem goes away. If this fixes it, then send as much info as you can about your previous PHP config to the PHP bug list.

Comment: symcbean, can you explain to me what is: "running the threaded Apache rather than the prefork? And PHP as a module?" and what is fastCGI
Thank you.

Comment: Is this still a problem? If so, what version of PHP and Apache are you using, and what does phpinfo() show for "Server API"?

Answer (score 0):

I am perhaps not answering your question but what if you instead of making your scripts return hello in one and world in the other instead output something a bit less static like the date and time.

```
script1.php
echo "Script1:".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."<br>";

script2.php
echo "Script2:".date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."<br>";
```

That way you will know if this is caused by some caching.